# JSOUP Parsing in Android

Tags: android, jsoup

I've been through countless examples and questions here, and I'm still unable to parse the following page using JSOUP:

[CBS Sports Player Search](http://www.cbssports.com/info/search#q=tom%20brady)

I am trying to get the following lines from the page (highlighted in blue):

[image]

and

[image]

Edit:  I've tried a selector as shown:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://solr.cbssports.com/solr/select/?q=fantasy%20Tom%20Brady")
                .timeout(30000)
                .get();

Element resultLinks = doc.select("#docs > div:nth-child(1) > img").first();
Log.i(TAG, "img: " + resultLinks);
```

However, the above returns null.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Josh

Comment: Looks like a simple selector would do. Where do you have problems? Show us your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is not possible, since there's *no* `img` tag in the linked document.

You get the second element with following code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://solr.cbssports.com/solr/select/?q=fantasy%20Tom%20Brady")
        .timeout(30000)
        .get();


Element tomBrady = doc.select("str[name=content]:matchesOwn(12 Tom Brady, QB Player Page)").first();

System.out.println(tomBrady);
```

---

Here's the only element containing an url to an image from the linked content:

```
<str name="img_url">http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/football/nfl/players/60x80/187741.jpg</str>
```

As stated in the comments, curiously the elements i get from the link differ from yours.

Since this is the only `str`-tag with `name=img_url` you can simply take the first one you find (= `first()`):

```
Element imgUrl = doc.select("str[name=img_url]").first();
String url = imgUrl.text();
```

If there's a possibility of more `img_url`'s, you better select the *top node* you need and select the proper url-element from those.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the 'href' link just below the img?  I am truly only need the id number that is associated with both those items (187741).

Comment: Of course it's possible. But the content is very different to yours in the screens. Put i'll edit some code into my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The additional code helped me get the line for the image.

Comment: I understand why you are seeing something different.  I had two different pages I was attempting to get the same info from.  The link in my original question is different than the link in my code.  Can you take a look here: http://www.cbssports.com/info/search#q=TOM%20BRADY

Comment: I see - but with that link there's another problem: The content is generated from javascript - and jsoup doesn't support (execute) those. The solution: Use a java JS-library like HtmlUnit, execute the scripts and parse the result as usual with jsoup.